# Cannot Connect to MySQL local server with SequelPro MySQL said: Incorrect database name

Tags: mysql, unix, sequelpro

I have create a mysql database locally in the unix macos Mojave environment, when entering mysql and entering command

```
mysql> show databases;

+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| cms_blog           |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

then when entering sequelpro I attempt to connect to 'cms_blog'

Host: 127.0.0.1
default root and password for mysql

This is the error I am seeing

[image]

I'm wondering if because the database has no tables I am seeing this error, or because sequelpro may be looking to a mamp mysql conf file rather than the homebrew mysql I am using via cli. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you typed a space at the end of the name.

Comment: @Barmar That was the issue, and I am scared thinking how long it would have taken me on my own.

Comment: Paying attention to little details is important when working with computers.